# How can I disable warnings on package level in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a folder of source files (say `src/main/java`), which contains two super-packages:

- `com.blah.generated`
- `com.blah.software`

The `com.blah.generated` code is generated by a tool which cannot be run at every compilation and is checked in to version control. We never change it, it is occasionally re-generated when there's a new dependency on a new release.

The generated code has 100s of warnings, which I want to get rid of. I don't have access to the generator code, nor can I relocate the package to a different folder.

Obviously I have a source folder pointing to `src/main/java`. I tried to exclude the `com.blah.generated` package, but then the `com.blah.software` using it fails to compile.

I tried adding a second source folder pointing to the same folder, and excluding `com.blah.software` so that I can turn on "Ignore optional compile problems", but Eclipse complains (however there's no overlapping between the two folders):

> Build path contains duplicate entry: 'src/main/java' for project 'blah'

I also tried filtering the `Problems` view to

> Include selected element and its children EXCEPT the `com.blah.generated`.

but there's no such option.

Comment: I have never seen package level suppressing of warnings but you can write this line before the class declaration : `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` for all warnings in the class to be suppressed. May be you can do this to all classes in the package ? You can also pass in multiple arguments along with unchecked

Comment: I know about @SuppressWarnings, but I'm talking about generated code! That is: no code modification or restructuring, just Eclipse IDE setup.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, Eclipse Juno introduced such a capability:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/whatsNew/jdt_whatsnew.html#JavaCompiler

Comment: I tried that (already described above), getting this error: `Build path contains duplicate entry: 'src/main/java' for project 'blah'`. It is because I have 1 and only 1 source folder in which I want to disable 1 package.